# Is there a word to describe a conversation long past saving?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the right word or words to describe a conversation that has gotten so hopelessly confused and misunderstood that there is no hope of salvaging it?

Comment: Do you want a noun or an adjective? A sample sentence with a _____ would help. Do fruitless or futile (adjectives) or morass (noun) meet your needs?

Comment: Why would we maintain anything that doesn't make any sense in the first place? Do you have an example of what you're thinking of?

Comment: Are you talking about *saving* as in keeping a historical record (*preserving*), or are you talking about it still being worthwhile (*pursuing*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) noun: [**morass**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morass) - Could refer to any predicament that was as murky, confusing, or difficult to navigate as a literal swamp or quagmire.

2) verb: [**muddle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muddle) - To make turbid or muddy: To mix confusedly: To make a mess of.

3) noun: [**imbroglio**](http://Shorter%20Oxford%20English%20Dictionary) - A state of great confusion; a confused misunderstanding. (derived from the *archaic* meaning of "A confused heap."

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like "pointless."  A word that might be used by one party just before walking away.

"This conversation is pointless" or

"This conversation has become pointless"